# Assign NA to a variable based on Group and ifelse condition

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

I'm trying to assign NA value in column `RAIN_15`, if any row in `RAIN_15` has value > 100 then all observations corresponding to that `gr`  in `RAIN_15` will be replaced by `NA`. Sample data is as given below:

```
   TRGCODE RAIN   DATE    TIME gr RAIN_15
    6155   0.0 2015-06-18 0000 17     0.0
    6155   0.0 2015-06-18 0015 17     0.0
    6155   0.0 2015-06-18 0030 17     0.0
    6155   0.0 2015-06-18 0045 17     0.0
    6155   0.0 2015-06-18 0100 17     0.0
    6155   0.0 2015-06-18 0115 17     0.0
    6155   0.0 2015-06-18 0130 17     0.0
    6155   0.0 2015-06-18 0145 17     0.0
    6155   0.0 2015-06-18 0200 17     0.0
    6155   0.0 2015-06-18 0215 17     0.0
    6155   0.0 2015-06-18 0230 17     0.0
    6155   0.0 2015-06-18 0245 17     0.0
    6155   0.2 2015-06-18 0300 17     0.2
    6155 123.7 2015-06-18 0315 17   123.5
    6155 127.0 2015-06-18 0330 17     3.3
    6155 127.0 2015-06-18 0345 17     0.0
    6155 127.0 2015-06-18 0400 17     0.0
    6155 127.0 2015-06-18 0415 17     0.0
    6155 127.0 2015-06-18 0430 17     0.0
    6155 127.0 2015-06-18 0445 17     0.0
    6155 127.0 2015-06-18 0500 17     0.0
    6155 141.7 2015-06-18 0515 17    14.7
    6155 594.3 2015-06-18 0530 17   452.6
    6155    NA 2015-06-18 0545 17      NA
    6155    NA 2015-06-18 0600 17      NA
```

Data has thousands of such rows where `gr` is group based on `TIME`. Here `RAIN_15` has value > 100, so all observations in `RAIN_15` for corresponding to `gr` 17 should be replaced by `NA`.
I tried with

```
df_v1 <- df %>% group_by(TRGCODE, gr) %>% mutate(RAIN_15 = ifelse(any(RAIN_15 > 100), NA, RAIN_15))
```

but it is replacing RAIN_15 values with 0. If I remove `any` in `ifelse` then it is just replacing values > 100 in `RAIN_15` by NA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the sake of completeness, here are two data.table approaches:

1. `if() ... else` by group
2. Update join with a lookup table

#### 1. `if() ... else` by group

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, RAIN_15 := if (any(RAIN_15 > 100)) NA else RAIN_15, by = gr][]
```

> ```
>     TRGCODE  RAIN       DATE  TIME    gr RAIN_15
>  1:    6155   0.0 2015-06-18     0    17      NA
>  2:    6155   0.0 2015-06-18    15    17      NA
>  3:    6155   0.0 2015-06-18    30    17      NA
>  4:    6155   0.0 2015-06-18    45    17      NA
>  5:    6155   0.0 2015-06-18   100    17      NA
> ...
> 20:    6155 127.0 2015-06-18   445    17      NA
> 21:    6155 127.0 2015-06-18   500    17      NA
> 22:    6155 141.7 2015-06-18   515    17      NA
> 23:    6155 594.3 2015-06-18   530    17      NA
> 24:    6155    NA 2015-06-18   545    17      NA
> 25:    6155    NA 2015-06-18   600    17      NA
> 26:    6155   0.0 2015-06-18     0    18       0
> 27:    6155   0.0 2015-06-18    15    18       0
>     TRGCODE  RAIN       DATE  TIME    gr RAIN_15
> ```

Note that I have used a modified sample dataset with an additional group (rows 26, 27) for testing.

This approach uses an `if() ... else` clause instead of calling the `fifelse()` function as in [waldi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72301721/3817004).

The reason is that `any()` already is an aggregation function which always returns a logical vector *of length one*. The other point is that the elements of `RAIN_15` should be replaced *by the same value* `NA`. `fifelse()` is a vector function which repeats the decision element by element which is a waste in this case.

However, this approach has the drawback that *all* elements of column `RAIN_15` are replaced even for those groups where this is not necessary at all.

#### 2. Update join with a lookup table

This approach will only update rows where necessary:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[df[, which(any(RAIN_15 > 100)), by = gr], on = .(gr), RAIN_15 := NA][]
```

Here, `df` is joined with a *lookup table* which contains the group ids `gr` which need to be updated by reference. Other groups will stay untouched.

The *lookup table* is created by

```
df[, which(any(RAIN_15 > 100)), by = gr]
```

> ```
>       gr    V1
> 1:    17     1
> ```

It contains only group ids which fulfill the condition. Column `V1` can be ignored.

#### Data

As mentioned above the modified sample dataset includes 2 additional rows of another group for testing/demonstration.

```
library(data.table)
df <- fread("
   TRGCODE RAIN   DATE    TIME gr RAIN_15
    6155   0.0 2015-06-18 0000 17     0.0
    6155   0.0 2015-06-18 0015 17     0.0
    6155   0.0 2015-06-18 0030 17     0.0
    6155   0.0 2015-06-18 0045 17     0.0
    6155   0.0 2015-06-18 0100 17     0.0
    6155   0.0 2015-06-18 0115 17     0.0
    6155   0.0 2015-06-18 0130 17     0.0
    6155   0.0 2015-06-18 0145 17     0.0
    6155   0.0 2015-06-18 0200 17     0.0
    6155   0.0 2015-06-18 0215 17     0.0
    6155   0.0 2015-06-18 0230 17     0.0
    6155   0.0 2015-06-18 0245 17     0.0
    6155   0.2 2015-06-18 0300 17     0.2
    6155 123.7 2015-06-18 0315 17   123.5
    6155 127.0 2015-06-18 0330 17     3.3
    6155 127.0 2015-06-18 0345 17     0.0
    6155 127.0 2015-06-18 0400 17     0.0
    6155 127.0 2015-06-18 0415 17     0.0
    6155 127.0 2015-06-18 0430 17     0.0
    6155 127.0 2015-06-18 0445 17     0.0
    6155 127.0 2015-06-18 0500 17     0.0
    6155 141.7 2015-06-18 0515 17    14.7
    6155 594.3 2015-06-18 0530 17   452.6
    6155    NA 2015-06-18 0545 17      NA
    6155    NA 2015-06-18 0600 17      NA
    6155   0.0 2015-06-18 0000 18     0.0
    6155   0.0 2015-06-18 0015 18     0.0
")
```

Answer (score 1):

With `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df_v1)
df_v1[,RAIN_15:=fifelse(rep(any(RAIN_15>100,na.rm=T),.N),NA_real_,RAIN_15),by=gr][]

   TRGCODE  RAIN       DATE TIME gr RAIN_15
 1:    6155   0.0 2015-06-18    0 17      NA
 2:    6155   0.0 2015-06-18   15 17      NA
 3:    6155   0.0 2015-06-18   30 17      NA
 4:    6155   0.0 2015-06-18   45 17      NA
 5:    6155   0.0 2015-06-18  100 17      NA
 6:    6155   0.0 2015-06-18  115 17      NA
 7:    6155   0.0 2015-06-18  130 17      NA
 8:    6155   0.0 2015-06-18  145 17      NA
 9:    6155   0.0 2015-06-18  200 17      NA
10:    6155   0.0 2015-06-18  215 17      NA
11:    6155   0.0 2015-06-18  230 17      NA
12:    6155   0.0 2015-06-18  245 17      NA
13:    6155   0.2 2015-06-18  300 17      NA
14:    6155 123.7 2015-06-18  315 17      NA
15:    6155 127.0 2015-06-18  330 17      NA
16:    6155 127.0 2015-06-18  345 17      NA
17:    6155 127.0 2015-06-18  400 17      NA
18:    6155 127.0 2015-06-18  415 17      NA
19:    6155 127.0 2015-06-18  430 17      NA
20:    6155 127.0 2015-06-18  445 17      NA
21:    6155 127.0 2015-06-18  500 17      NA
22:    6155 141.7 2015-06-18  515 17      NA
23:    6155 594.3 2015-06-18  530 17      NA
24:    6155    NA 2015-06-18  545 17      NA
25:    6155    NA 2015-06-18  600 17      NA
    TRGCODE  RAIN       DATE TIME gr RAIN_15
```

Comment: It is changing observations for same group id ````gr```` from other ````TRGCODE```` as well. ````by = .(TRGCODE, gr)````also doing the same.

Comment: could you provide example data to reproduce the problem you're encountering?

Comment: sorry it worked well now, was having issue with ````dplyr```` package in using ````group_by````.

Answer (score 0):

```
df <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = 'TRGCODE RAIN   DATE    TIME gr RAIN_15
    6155   0.0 2015-06-18 0000 17     0.0
    6155   0.0 2015-06-18 0015 17     0.0
    6155   0.0 2015-06-18 0030 17     0.0
    6155   0.0 2015-06-18 0045 17     0.0
    6155   0.0 2015-06-18 0100 17     0.0
    6155   0.0 2015-06-18 0115 17     0.0
    6155   0.0 2015-06-18 0130 17     0.0
    6155   0.0 2015-06-18 0145 17     0.0
    6155   0.0 2015-06-18 0200 17     0.0
    6155   0.0 2015-06-18 0215 17     0.0
    6155   0.0 2015-06-18 0230 17     0.0
    6155   0.0 2015-06-18 0245 17     0.0
    6155   0.2 2015-06-18 0300 17     0.2
    6155 123.7 2015-06-18 0315 17   123.5
    6155 127.0 2015-06-18 0330 17     3.3
    6155 127.0 2015-06-18 0345 17     0.0
    6155 127.0 2015-06-18 0400 17     0.0
    6155 127.0 2015-06-18 0415 17     0.0
    6155 127.0 2015-06-18 0430 17     0.0
    6155 127.0 2015-06-18 0445 17     0.0
    6155 127.0 2015-06-18 0500 17     0.0
    6155 141.7 2015-06-18 0515 17    14.7
    6155 594.3 2015-06-18 0530 17   452.6
    6155    NA 2015-06-18 0545 17      NA
    6155    NA 2015-06-18 0600 17      NA')

x=aggregate(RAIN_15 ~ gr, data = df, max)

x$RAIN_15=ifelse(x$RAIN_15>100, NA,x$RAIN_15)

df$RAIN_15=merge(df,x, all.x = TRUE, by="gr")[7]
```